# Wrong unix time from parsed DateTime

Tags: javascript, datetime, parsing

Here is code

```
const dateStr = '1989-11-11T03:34';
let date = new Date(dateStr);
console.log(date.toUTCString());
console.log(+date);
```

And output:

```
Fri, 10 Nov 1989 22:34:00 GMT
626740440000 <--- far future
```

Why unix time is in far future?

Here is [Playcode](https://playcode.io/1038204) link

Comment: new Date(Date.parse(dateStr));

Comment: @SyedArsalanHussain - What are you trying to say there? That's going to do the same thing `new Date(dateStr)` does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you can see the variable which is parsing the date `Date(Date.parse(datestr))`

Comment: @SyedArsalanHussain - Sorry, I'm still not getting what you're saying...?

Comment: `new Date(Date.parse(datestr))` will produce an identical result to `new Date(datestr)` per ECMA-262. '1989-11-11T03:34' will be parsed as local, so the instant in time it represents is dependent on host system regional settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not wrong.

You seem to have two issues with what you're getting:

1. The time isn't the same in your `toISOString` output.
2. The number you're getting from `+date` isn't what you expect.

But both are correct:

1. The string has no timezone indicator on it, so since it's a date+time string, it's parsed as **local time**. This is covered by the [Date Time String Format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format) section of the specification. But your output is showing GMT (because `toISOString` uses GMT).
2. `626740440000` is the number of **milliseconds** since The Epoch, not seconds as it was in the original Unix epoch scheme. This is covered by the [Time Values and Time Range](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-time-values-and-time-range) section of the specification.

If you want to parse your string as UTC (loosely, GMT), add a `Z` to the end of it indicating that't is in GMT.

If you want the number of *seconds* since The Epoch, divide `+date` by `1000` (perhaps rounding or flooring the result).

Comment: My really bad. I know about milliseconds but somehow I forgot for them...the end of working week. And thanks for `Z`